# How to hide the source view of a page with htaccess?

Tags: html, .htaccess, web, hide, view-source

As I said in the title, how to hide the source view of a page with htaccess ? Like that:

```
(fake code) IF [URL START WITH "view-soure"] - DONT_SHOW_CODE_PLZ
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

The `view-source:` URL prefix is handled *internally* by the browser.

The server doesn't get to see it, so server-side code can't trigger based on it.

Comment: So how can I protect my code from thieves?

Comment: Copyright law. You'll need a lawyer. (Odds are the code isn't worth protecting anyway).

Comment: _"So how can I protect my code from thieves?"_ - that is a question countless people have asked before you already. And the answer is, for the most part - **you can't**. The web is build on openness, you can not really "hide" client-side code, at most you can obfuscate it. (But then again, most people asking this kind of question are on such a beginner level, that their code usually isn't worth protecting from "stealing" in the first place.)